# multiple classes calling a method in a class in another file

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I created a method that is in a partial class in App_Code. This method would replace the same type of method that would otherwise be in many files.

Since it would be called from many files, it would probably be called and used very frequently especially because of this.

Would this overload this class? I'm not saying what would most likely happen, I'm just asking if it would be even remotely possible?

Comment: Do you mean "multiple classes *call* that method" or "multiple classes should *include* that same method"?

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand your question: A method doesn't care how often it is called.

However, you should care if the method takes long to return (ie. extensive work on the database which takes an abnormal amount of time).

Comment: Well, let me put it this way, with some theoretical thought as well. Let's say this method is very vital to the whole application, and let's say that this method inside this class in App_Code would have to be called let's say, theoretically, it gets called 500+ times a second, because so many different files would be referencing it. Are you telling me that this would not effect anything at all, and everything would be completely fine? The way you spoke about it, it sounds like that's what you mean, I just wanted to be absolutely sure, and thanks.

Comment: It entirely depends on the content of the method. If you are just manipulating the data the method is called with - no problem. If you need access to a limited resource (database connection, file access, transaction, lock) it will be problematic and will slow your application down.

Comment: I had a feeling that was probably the truth. Yeah, file access is involved, and also, making this method so modular and dynamic instead of file specific, would require a few more input strings for when the method is called. Thanks again, and thanks to Adeel as well...

Answer (score 0):

On compilation, the compiler combine different partial classes on the basis of same name into one class. so if there is a difference in signature of method, but with same name, it is allowed and is method overloading. Otherwise the compile will throw error if it found same function(same function means same name and signature).